# How to make GetVoices() detect and return all voices installed in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I run .GetVoices() on SpVoice object and it doesn't return all voices, it return only Zira, Hazel, and David.

My program detects for global Ctrl+C twice fast and speaks the text in clipboard using the voice (and its language) with the SpVoice object .Speak.

```
public static SpVoice SP = new SpVoice();



foreach (SpeechLib.ISpeechObjectToken v in SP.GetVoices())
    {
       comboBoxVoice.Items.Add(v.GetDescription(49));
    }


SP.Speak(s, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync | SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak);
```

SpVoice object .GetVoices() should return all voices installed in Windows 10, I read somewhere that it's a 32/64 bit problem, I changed my debug CPU to x86 and in the debug the other installed voices in Windows 10 64 bit still didn't appear.